# If in mysql JOIN PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

im trying to do this :

in the controller i did:

```
foreach($troublesome_pupil as $u)
array_push($bad_pupils,$u->id)
```

i send $bad_pupils to my model and before the query i do :

```
$bad_pupils = implode(',', $bad_pupils);

Select user.name from user
IF (user.id NOT IN '$bad_pupils')
JOIN `marksheet` ON marksheet.id = user.id
JOIN `holiday` ON holiday.id = user.id
ENDIF
```

basically $bad_pupils is an array , so i check for user id in that array (i have already taken care of the array using implode) if found then only join the two tables , else go ahead

Also if in my select statement say example : i have

```
select (user.name , marksheet.marks) ..
```

if the row gets skipped in the IF statement what will be the value of the marks column for that row ?

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: y are answers dissappearing ?

Comment: I think that If work in sentences and not in queries, I.E, in store procedures, triggers, begin-end http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html I'm not sure if you can mixed it that way

Comment: @jcho360 `IF` works also in queries. IMHO the OP should consider having a look http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: @Havelock yes, but that IF is different, this if even need the ENDIF, this one is more for transactions I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use this?

```
    SELECT user.name, marksheet.marks, holiday.holiday 
      FROM user
 LEFT JOIN marksheet ON marksheet.id = user.id AND user.id NOT IN ($bad_pupils)
 LEFT JOIN holiday ON holiday.id = user.id AND user.id NOT IN ($bad_pupils)
```